# IOS 6.0 MKAnnotation callout bubble strange behavior

Tags: mkmapview, mkannotation

I resently faced some strange issue on IOS 6.0 related to MKAnnotation (part of MKMap Kit)
May be some of you fased the same, or have idea or advise how to skip/avoid/solve it.

Here it is
I need some Pins on my map with callout bubbles (contains titles & subtitles nothing more)
When i pressing on it callout starts. Due to user comfort I've added observer to center pin:

```
(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context{
    NSString *action = (NSString*)context;
    if([[change valueForKey:@"new"] intValue] == 1 && [action isEqualToString:@"GMAP_ANNOTATION_SELECTED"])  {
        if ([((MKAnnotationView*) object).annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomPlacemark class]]) {
            CustomPlacemark *place = ((MKAnnotationView*) object).annotation;


                       [mapView setCenterCoordinate:place.coordinate animated:YES];            
        }
    }
}
```

On ios 5.1 or above everything looks & works fine (pin centering after press, callout bubbles shows above centered horizontally), but on IOS 6.0 behavior is strage, pin centering as well, but callout bubble not, even if it's width enough to fill screen horizontally it could appear partially beyond screen.

Haven't found any solution or options to manually setup appearance behavior. Have any advices?

Thx for further answers, and sorry for my English.